# Getting _source of elasticsearch document using Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using the thing elasticsearch Python wrapper. I can't figure out how to get only the _source of a document. How can I get the Python wrapper to issue a call similar to this:

```
http://..../index/type/id/_source
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to call [`get_source`](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.get_source) like this:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch()

source = es.get_source(index='index', doc_type='type', id='id')
```